Bow to Knuckles in Sky Sanctuary Zone: why (so secret)?
In Sonic & Knuckles when playing as Sonic (or in Sonic 3 & Knuckles when playing as Tails or Sonic & Tails) you start Sky Sanctuary Zone by landing with the teleporter and Knuckles being exhausted, kneeling on the ground and gasping. Because in Hidden Palace he was electrocuted by Dr. Ivo Robotnik while fighting off the Master Emerald. His last action now is to activate a bridge so Sonic (and Tails) can go on. Knuckles remains on the switch he pressed.
Next to the switch there's a short range to stand on, where when you press Down you interact with Knuckles, who then changes his animation into a frame of turning his head, and then waving you to go on alone (which can be repeated as per bowing). This is documented in Sonic Retro > Sonic & Knuckles > Hidden content > Bow to Knuckles. Sonic's action is to hold his head down (in his hands), but Tails' action fits much better, as he lowers his head but still looks up - as if he directly looks into Knuckles' eyes from below:

I found out about this myself back then, but over the years/decades never found a hint of it on the internet. I ended up adding/commenting that easter egg to 2-3 websites to make it more known and see in Sonic Retro's article history that it wasn't in there up to 15:50, 12 May 2019‎ either.
After all the years I still ask myself:

Why is this animation change only triggered by pressing Down? Looking back into Knuckles' direction could have been enough (and easier to discover).
Story-wise this is even more bonding both, now that Knuckles knows Sonic isn't the bad guy. But why is it kept so secret?
Is it just coincidence that Tails alone fits this scenario best (I actually found out about this playing Tails alone)? Are there details between Knuckles and Tails only (which can't be found between Knuckles and Sonic)?

The only other thing being equally this easter-eggish (which are rather unusual in the 16-bit games IMO) I can think of are:

Sonic CD's statue room in the Wacky Workbench Zone and maybe
Sonic & Knuckles' Death Egg Zone Act 1 having a passage that only Tails can finish, as it ends with needing him to fly up (bottom middle of level map).


reminds me about the out-of-reach rings in the 8bit version of Sonic 2 that almost seemed to point to Tails being playable at some point. You can see a clear example here
